In Windows is there a way to check which port can be opened
I am experiencing an issue where port 64120 through 64130 cannot be opened.These ports are needed for the Eclipse SonarLint plugin.
The ports are not in use, checked with netstat, tcpview and portqry.
There is something or some setting preventing those ports to be opened.
I would like to create a list of all ports that cannot be opened. I hope that if I know the blocked ranges I can find out what is blocking them.
Is there a command that creates such a list ?
Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2
How does the blocked ports issue manifest itself
PS C:\workspace> netstat -anp | findstr 64120

returns nothing, also tcpview and other utilities do not show port 64120 as being in use.

Sonarlint plugin shows errors during start

Starting SonarLint for Eclipse 9.3.3006
Error while starting port: 64120, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64121, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64122, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64123, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64124, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64125, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64126, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64127, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64128, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64129, Address already in use: bind
Error while starting port: 64130, Address already in use: bind


Using python tcp_server example

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html
python3.11.exe c:/cce/workspaces/develop128/tcp_server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\workspace\tcp_server.py", line 24, in <module>
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\socketserver.py", line 472, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions


Firewall ?
I suspect firewall and other system admin tooling to be possible causes, but at the moment I cannot check. I want to create the list of block port so that I can communicate that to our system administrators


Ports 49152 and above can be used by any process. Windows has no restrictions or permission requirements.

I'm experiencing an issue where port 64120 through 64130 cannot be opened - How did you determine that?

Checked Windows Firewall?

@joeqwerty He gets error messages from SonarLint without actually seing any open port.

"system admin tooling"  probably has log files that can be used to confirm. Firewall logs, endpoint security logs, ProcMon traces, all of these are useful to show actionable information.

My main question is . Can I create a list of ports that can be opened. I cannot find any info in the eventlogs

I created a small python program that tries to open all ports and lists the result.
import socket

def check_port(port):

    try:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
            result = "available"
    except OSError as e:
        result = f"closed: {e}"
    return result

def main():
    # Define the range of ports you want to check
    start_port = 2
    end_port = 65535

    first_port = 1
    last_port = first_port
    first_result = check_port(first_port)

    for port in range(start_port, end_port + 1):
        result = check_port(port)
        if (result == first_result):
            last_port = port
        if (result != first_result or port == end_port):
            print(f"{first_port}-{last_port} : {first_result}")
            first_port = port
            last_port = first_port
            first_result = result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

sample output (trimmed)
python -u "tcp_testports.py"
...
2180-3388 : available
3389-3389 : closed: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
3390-5039 : available
5040-5040 : closed: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
5041-5984 : available
5985-5985 : closed: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
5986-7679 : available
...

The port locking issue has gone away. I disabled the Internet connection sharing service and rebooted. That seemed to fix the issue, but when I check the ICS service has been started again, so I'm not sure what was blocking the ports. I'll keep this code in case I encounter the same issue again.

2179 is available and closed?

fixed issue reported by Toto
